# Widget for iOS does not update the time in the release

Tags: ios, flutter, swiftui, widgetkit

I have an application written in flutter. I have added a widget that displays the current time.

The widget should show the current time in different time zones. Everything works fine as long as the application is running in debug mode.

But after loading the application in TestFligth or running it in release mode, the time stops updating.

```
struct CitiesClockProvider: TimelineProvider {
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> CitiesClockEntry {
        CitiesClockEntry(date: Date(), listCities: defaultList)
    }

    func getSnapshot(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (CitiesClockEntry) -> ()) {
        let data = UserDefaults.init(suiteName: widgetGroupId)
        let list: [CitiesEntry]? = parseToCitiesList(string: data?.string(forKey: "listCities"))
        let entry = CitiesClockEntry(date: Date(), listCities: list ?? defaultList)
        
        completion(entry)
    }

    func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
        var entries: [CitiesClockEntry] = []
        let data = UserDefaults.init(suiteName: widgetGroupId)
        let list: [CitiesEntry]? = parseToCitiesList(string: data?.string(forKey: "listCities"))

        let currentDate = Date()
        let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .second, value: 1, to: currentDate)!
        let entry = CitiesClockEntry(date: entryDate, listCities: list ?? [])
        entries.append(entry)

        let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .after(entryDate))

        let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { (timer) in
            WidgetCenter.shared.reloadTimelines(ofKind: "WidgetCitiesClock")
            completion(timeline)
        }
        timer.tolerance = 5.0
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn’t expect that timer to work. There is a budget for how many times a widget can reload but it is at apple’s discretion . When in debug mode the budget is much more generous and depending on settings you can bypass.

Comment: The budget is about once every 15 minutes.